# javafx rotate to left

Tags: java, javafx, rotation

```
      Point2D a = new Point2D(e.getX(), e.getY());
      Point2D b = new Point2D(atCenter.getCenterX(), atCenter.getCenterY());
      double deg = a.angle(b);
      double test =(Math.abs(line1.getStartX() - line1.getEndX()) + 
      Math.abs(line1.getStartY() - line1.getEndY()));
      System.out.println("test:" + test);
      System.out.println("X:" + e.getX() + "\ny: " + e.getY());
      System.out.println("deg:" + Math.toRadians(deg) * 100);

      pane.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(deg-360, atCenter.getCenterX(), atCenter.getCenterY()));
```

Hello! This is my code and I am trying to rotate the pane by moving my mouse.

when I drag the mouse, it will gives me the angle but it only works x ++ and y ++ if I drag to left or down, the rotation is not working.

is there any way to fix this??

thank you!!

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: sorry i figured it out!! Thank you for reply!